# Error Dojo Widget in IE only 'Already registered with that id '

Tags: javascript, dojo, dijit.dialog

I have a dojo widget, when trying to open in IE only it is showing error

> " Already registered with that id "Frm1gpop"

```
var formDlg = new xwt.widget.layout.Dialog({
  title: DialogTitle + "  Selection",
  defaultButtonLabel: "Cancel",
  "class": "frmdes",
  "id": "frmdlgpop",
  style: "width:70%!important;"
});

formDlg.startup();
```

Comment: I am creating it is first time only

Comment: does your widget is declared as data-dojo-type in html ?

Comment: We don't have a html file only js.  We have a widget library in our project. We are just include in our page

Answer (score -1):

Dojo doesn't allow you to have multiple widgets registered with the same id.  I would posit that the code which calls `formDlg.startup();` is being called from multiple places.

Comment: No it's called once only

Comment: It's working fine in Chrome and Firefox. But ie is not support this

Comment: comment can't be posted as an answer. Sorry